# Get current array of hidden html element value on the click of array of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, dom

I have html elements as:

```
<input type=hidden class=txtCustomerId value=".parent::current()." />";
<input type=button class=printToTextarea value='Get to box' />
```

and jquery:

```
$(".printToTextarea").on("click", function () {
    var array = $('.txtCustomerId').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
     loadxmldoc(array);
 });
```

It passing all elements as array from hidden field with class name `txtCustomerId` while I need only current element when button click. Button is also array and both should have same index.

Comment: Is that the actual code layout? Makes a big difference in the answer

Comment: Use `this` to get the clicked element

Comment: @then I need another element value after button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code using `eq()` and `index()` meet the requirement at much extent.

```
$(".printToTextarea").on("click", function () {
    var i = $('.printToTextarea').index(this);

    var custid=$('.txtCustomerId').eq(i).val();

     loadxmldoc(custid);
    $("#textInput").focus();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('.txtCustomerId')
```

to:

```
$(this).prev('.txtCustomerId')
```

Comment: $(this).prev('.txtCustomerId').val() shows undefined in alert

Comment: I think $(this) can be used if we get value from printToTextarea field

Comment: I see no result there

Comment: Do you have the browser's console open? You should debug with console, not alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are selecting all of the elements. So you need to select the one that is related. With your example, you would use prev() to get a reference to the element.

```js
$(".printToTextarea").on("click", function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var inputValue = button.prev(".txtCustomerId").val();
    console.log(inputValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=hidden class=txtCustomerId value="hello" />
<input type=button class=printToTextarea value='Get to box' />
```

But how you get the input really depends on your HTML. So if the structure is different than the two elements beside each other, than the way to select it would change.

Comment: Button and hidden elements both are arrays, so I want to get hidden element value when button click at same index.

Comment: Than use index() and eq(), but seems like going off the HTML structure would make sense...

Comment: yes I have done using same functions already and posting answer below, thanks